# Using level information from OpenStreetMap to show roads / tunnels / bridges in right level?

Tags: qgis, layers, order

OSM has information about the levels of road segments for example road crossing railway.

It is possible to order layers dynamically from the level attribute?

I only found one possibility in QGIS to order layers, but they are fixed and only manually set.

[image]